# Filter Redundant Data in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, linq-to-sql

I have a View that retrieves 2 or more same data in LNameByFName, displaying the same names. How can I display only 1 one these names regardless of its index?

I can use `FirstOrDefault()` but I already have `.ToList()`

```
public IEnumerable<EmployeeWithEmail> GetAllEmployeesWithEmail(int x)
{
      using (var context = new SQL_TA_SCOREBOARDEntities1())
      {
        return (from ea in context.View_1
                join vh in context.View_2 on (Int16)ea.EmpNo equals vh.EmpNo
                join rl in context.View_3 on ea.RoleID equals rl.id into outer_join
                from subjoin in outer_join where ea.GroupID == x
                select new EmployeeWithEmail
                {

                    EmpNum = ea.EmpNo ?? 0,
                    Role = subjoin.Role,
                    EmailAddress = vh.EmailAddress,
                    LNameByFname = vh.LNameByFName,
                    Active2 = ea.Active ?? false

                }).ToList();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep the "group" inline, using your existing query syntax, try this:

```
return (from ea in context.View_1
        join vh in context.View_2 on (Int16)ea.EmpNo equals vh.EmpNo
        join rl in context.View_3 on ea.RoleID equals rl.id into outer_join
            from subjoin in outer_join where ea.GroupID == x
        group new
        {
            ea.EmpNo,
            subjoin.Role,
            vh.EmailAddress,
            vh.LNameByFName,
            ea.Active
        } by vh.LNameByFName into grp
        let item = grp.FirstOrDefault()
        select new EmployeeWithEmail
        {
            EmpNum = item.EmpNo ?? 0,
            Role = item.Role,
            EmailAddress = item.EmailAddress,
            LNameByFname = item.LNameByFName,
            Active2 = item.Active ?? false
        }).ToList();
```

FYI, when you use `FirstOrDefault()`, you generally want to test for `null` too, something like `EmpNum = (item != null ? item.EmpNo ?? 0 : -1),`. Otherwise you may get a `NullReferenceException`.

But I *think* your safe in this case... I can't see how a "group" wouldn't have at least one item in it.

Comment: Aw. I get 'Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<string>' because it is not a delegate type at "group" in 'group new' and in 'rl': does not exist in the current context.

Comment: 'NotSupportedException: The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.' Hmm. :|

Comment: Thanks Grant! It works amazingly! I'll be able to share this with some of my co-student programmers. :)

Comment: Yes I had that minor issue encountered before. My gratitude! :)

Answer (score 1):

To eliminate duplicates, use GroupBy followed by Take:

```
   IQueryable<EmployeeWithEmail> query = ...;
   // group by the value you want to be unique
   var queryWithoutDuplicates = query.GroupBy(e => e.LNameByFName)
       // then select the first (arbitrary since there's no order) member of each group
       .SelectMany(g => g.Take(1))
       .ToList();
```

If you have already pulled the results into memory, you can also use the overload of Distinct() that takes an IEqualityComparer:

```
 // AsEnumerable() pulls us into memory, where we can use EqualityComparers
 var queryWithoutDuplicates = query.AsEnumerable()
     // do a distinct using a comparer based on the key you want to be unique
     .Distinct(EqualityComparers.Create((EmployeeWithEmail e) => e.LNameByFName))
     .ToList();
```

EqualityComparers.Create is defined at: http://www.codeducky.org/10-utilities-c-developers-should-know-part-two/.

Answer (score -1):

After your `select` and before your `.ToList()` call [`.Distinct()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) passing an [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.IEqualityComparer.aspx).

Comment: I'm sorry can you revise the code with that? I'm very new to LINQ and have no idea what IEQualityComparer is. LNameByFname = vh.LNameByFName.Distinct() ?

Comment: Not sure you can pass an EqualityComparer to Linq-to-SQL.

Comment: @user3483341 `IEqualityComparer` is an interface, you want to implement it, then you can pass your implementation to various methods that do comparisons. The docs can be found here; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Aron makes a good point, you need to use the `IEqualityComparer` on native objects, I'm pretty sure you can't redefine equality in SQL, there are strict definitions for the various types in an MS SQL db. What you can do is add this second level of filtering that takes executes using LINQ to Objects after the initial LINQ to SQL query returns.